# Meteor, ReactJS, MongoDB: Do something when user leaves page

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, meteor

I am trying to build a match-making algorithm that connects two random users, but I can't find a way to delete the connection (which is generated in a MongoDB collection, so I need to remove the query) when user leaves the page.

Comment: `Collection.remove({})` removes *all* documents from a mongodb collection, is that what you really want? You should look at *routing* in the context of Meteor (i.e. FlowRouter or React-Router depending on your front-end). A "query" is not removable. A "document" can be removed or a "subscription" can be stopped.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [window.onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) will be helpful here. It executes Javascript when the user leaves the page.

Meteor:

```
Meteor.startup(function(){
    $(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
        closingWindow();
    });
});

closingWindow = function(){
    ...
}
```

React:

```
componentDidMount() {
  window.addEventListener('beforeunload', this.handleLeavePage);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', this.handleLeavePage);
}

handleLeavePage() {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but none of the above works, I dont know why... I tried to do Collection.remove({}) on both of them but it deletes nothing when I leave the page.

Answer (score 0):

How Does the user trigger the leaving of page , is it via a button click? after a time interval? MongoDB is realtime , and if the connection between the two users is based from the database , setting the database connection to null or deleting its instance + the usage of publish and subscribe will do the trick. Here is an example:

```
      const CheckIfConnection  = Meteor.subscribe('collectionsubscription',userId1,userId2)
          if(CheckIfConnection.ready()){
                 const connection = Collection.'ConnectionCollectionName'.findOne();

                //Pass it on the component
           }
```

on the Component side , you can have a 'ComponentWillReceiveProps' that will be triggered when a prop ( Coming from the container ) has changed and that is if the connection is Gone. That would do the trick at your matching algorithm via database approach :)